# UIWebView Swipe-Gesture

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, swipe-gesture, uiswipegesturerecognizer

everything works in my code, but I get always warning by "swipeLeft.delegate =  self;"

The "self" is marked by this warning.

The warning is : Passing 'UIWebView *' to parameter of incompatible type

and

Passing 'viewCont *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type "id UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

What can I do??

My code:

```
#import "viewCont.h"

@implementation viewCont

@synthesize webView = webView_;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
//...code

// add Left 
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeftAction:)];
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    swipeLeft.delegate =  self;
    [webView_ addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

//code....
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Regarding line:

```
swipeLeft.delegate =  self;
```

Your controller needs to implement **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate** like follows:

```
@interface viewCont : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {

}

@end
```

I don't see any problematic code regarding webView warning in provided code.

Answer (score 0):

Is this class a child of UIWebView?

You are setting the target to self, make sure that that object is an instance or subclass of UIWebView. If you have the WebView set up as an instance variable you will need to set the target of the gesture recognizer to that instance.